# Kendo DropDownList not rendering properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Trying to make a simple dropdownlist to select "Y" or "N".

The dropdown looked correct, but the selection was not being reflected in the model in the [HttpPost] method.  I found an answer stating to remove the Name, so I did that, and now it displays the dropdown and an input box.

```
<label>SubmitAllPatients:  @Html.Label(Model.establishedSamplingPlan.SubmitAllPatients.ToString())</label>
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.establishedSamplingPlan.SubmitAllPatients)
    //.Name("SubmitAllPatients")
    .BindTo(new string[] { "N", "Y"})
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "max-width: 70px" }))
```

[Displays Correctly with Name (but doesn't update model)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cenZT.png)

[Displays Incorrectly without Name (but updates model)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tevm6.png)

Comment: The unwanted input box can appear if you have another control on the page with the same ID (or same model property in this case).  Can you check that?

Comment: Thank you!  I had @html.HiddenFor(m=>m.establishedSamplingPlan.SubmitAllPatients) a few lines before the snippet shown.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was given in the comments by Tawab Wakil.

Before adding this dropdown list, I was using this line to pass the value to the model in the `[HttpPost]` method:

```
@html.HiddenFor(m=>m.establishedSamplingPlan.SubmitAllPatients)
```

I removed that line, and it worked.